# the background doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, background

When I am using 'no-repeat' the background is working, but as soon as I change to 'no-repeat' there is no background. I am trying to define the background in CSS.

```
body
{ font: normal 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background: #4E5869;
  background-image:  url(../images/bg_body.jpg) no-repeat;
 }
```

Would appreciate your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`no-repeat` is a `background-repeat` value, not a `background-image` value...

```
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

OR:

```
background: #4E5869 url(...) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this:

```
body
{ font: normal 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #4E5869;
  background-image:  url(../images/bg_body.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Now the `background-color` and `background-image` are served separately.

When you call `background` inside of it, you can call first your `color` then your `image-url` `image-position` and `background-repeat`. But when you call say `background-image` then you call just the `image-url`

```
 body
    { font: normal 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #000;
      background-color: #4E5869;
      background-image:  url(../images/bg_body.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }
```

OR

```
body
    { font: normal 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #000;
      background: #4E5869 url(../images/bg_body.jpg) no-repeat;
     }
```

Comment: See my explanation to understand what I was trying to point out

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
body {
  font: normal 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background: #4E5869 url(../images/bg_body.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

`background-image` is the image, not any rules you wish to give. You can go with your style like this:

```
body {
  font: normal 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background: #4E5869;
  background-image:  url(../images/bg_body.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Pretty much equal.
Some stuff to read: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **no-repeat** as part of **background-image** (all that accepts, is the URL to the image)

You need to use **background-repeat**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: Maybe you don't like that site - but it still proves the point, and gives an example on how to utilize the feature he needs correctly ;)

Comment: In this case, maybe, but you would do much better to link to MDN.

Comment: It was just the first one that came up on google, and it gave the info they needed - which is why I quoted it <G>

Comment: The fact that it is top on Google is bad and something that will only continue if people keep linking to it because it's top on Google XD

Comment: changed to MDN now ;)